# Use FParsec on already tokenized UInt16 stream

Tags: parsing, f#, lexical-analysis, fparsec

I need to parse an already tokenized stream of type `UInt16 seq`.
How can I do this with FParsec?
All the top level functions I can find in the reference work on `charstream`s.

At the moment I convert the `UInt16`s to `char`s which seems silly.

Comment: So my suggestion to you since you are using F# for fun and profit as your learning resource is to not use FParsec at first. First code up your first working version using only what you learn from F# for fun and profit. Then make lots of good test cases and run your code against the test cases and then covert the code to use FParsec and run against your test cases.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on what you're trying to do?  If you're not working with character data though, FParsec probably isn't going to be the appropriate tool.

Comment: I gave this a close vote because you are not providing more info. I view SO as a place to help the community and by you not providing any more info you are not getting an answer and thus not helping the community. As such a Q&A that does not help the community should be closed and removed. Please add more details or delete the question. :)

Comment: IMO the question can be answered with the info provided. No need to go into messy details when there is a simple, general answer. My conclusion is, that it is not possible to use FParsec on anything else than a `CharStream`. Anyone disagrees? Shall I answer myself? I will accept an answer along those lines by somebody else. I solved the problem by basically re-implementing a simple version of FParsec using the [F# for fun and profit article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use FParsec on anything else than a `CharStream`.

I solved the problem by writing a simple parser combinator myself, using [this  article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators/).
Surprisingly this was only one day's worth of work.
I learned a lot about parser combinators in the process.